# How to initialize the object type of ActiveRecord's serialized object/store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization

I have an ActiveRecord model that uses the ActiveRecord`store` feature to turn a textfield into a Hash, to give the record pseudo-noSQL like behavior (ignore for the fact that I'm not using the `accessors` option):

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base 
   store :infodump
end 

book = Book.new
book.infodump[:color] = green
puts book.infodump[:color]
# => green
```

This works fine enough, but I want the `infodump` to be treated as a Hashie::Mash object so that I can do this:

```
book = Book.new
book.infodump.author_info = {name: 'Bob', location: {city: 'Manhattan', state: 'NY'}}
puts book.infodump.author_info.location.state
# => NY
```

If you're not familiar with the Hashie gem, it allows you to give useful features to a Hash...in this case, treating a hash key-store as if it were an object with dot-accessible attributes: https://github.com/intridea/hashie

The Mash object in particular automatically bestows these conveniences even upon nested hashes, which is why I want my `infodump` store to be treated as a Hashie::Mash object.

So how do I initialize that attribute to be a Hashie::Mash? I started off by doing a `before_initialize` callback to do something like this:

```
 def make_mash
     infodump = Hashie::Mash.new(infodump)
 end
```

But then that runs every time the object is instantiated...I only need this object conversion done once in the lifetime of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my models I use `serialize` which allows passing a type to serialize to/from

```
serialize :infodump, Array
```

this method serializes objects to yaml so `Hashie::Mash` needs to have respective methods implemented.